# I cannot use letter "o" with my keyboard. (Ubuntu 14.04) - Dell xps 17 702x

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys, character-set

After I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and then 14.04 right after, I cannot use caracter/letter "o" with my keyboard anymore.

I didn't customize any shrotcut and no shortcut with this letter is involved.

The layout is correct (classic french keyboard just like when I had older ubuntu version).

Edit : The layout is not the problem since : when I change the layout to an eglish qwerty or even arabic, the "o" key does not print anything n screen (console/text editor : in unity session).

Could you please help me, it's quite embarrassing..

My PC is a Dell xps 17 702x, if it may help.

Edit :

1 ) When I press the "o" key, I actually see the cursor blink like the computer aknoledged I pressed something, but nthing prints.

2) Hre it gets interresting : When I long-press the "o" key, after half a second, multiple "o" appear : "ooooooooo". It seams that only "fast-pressing" the "o" key is problematic !

Comment: Do you have a live CD or USB for a different Ubuntu version that you can boot up and test the keyboard with?

Comment: With a live cd I have no problem. I don't have any problem neither when I boot up with my Windows 7 partition.

Comment: It gets weirder :

1 ) When I press the "o" key, I actually see the cursor blink like the computer aknoledged I pressed something, but nthing prints.

2) Hre it gets interresting : When I long-press the "o" key, after half a second, multiple "o" appear : ooooooooo. It seams that only "fast-pressing" the "o" key is problematic !

Comment: Sorry for the people who'll get to that page thinking they would find a solution for this keyboard problem. I couldn't spend more time on this matter and I chosed to make a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.I don't recomend doing an automatic distribution upgrade (I did that directly : 13.04 -> 13.10 -> 14.04). It was a mess afterwards.
Just use dejadup for your personnal files, configurations and then go for a fresh install. I mean, who could believe such crap could even happen with a keypoard. It's from outer space.

Do a fresh install or get ready for a X-files episode on your favourite laptop.